# MongoDB get all documents where array values match

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure of document:

```
  {
    "input": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "last_name_hebrew",
          "text": "test1",
        },
      ],
    },
    "output": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "last_name_hebrew",
          "text": "test1"
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

I want to get all documents, where fields has object that has name of value `last_name_hebrew` as with `text` value of the `output.fields`.

For example in the given structure it would return this documents because `input.fields.name` is  `last_name_hebrew` and `text` is equal to the `text` in `output`.

Note I cannot guarantee that `fields` array in either `input` or `output` will have `name: last_name_hebrew` in the array.

How can I do so?

This is my try to first force the arrays to have document with `name` of `last_name_hebrew`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "input.fields": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "name": "last_name_hebrew"
    }
  },
  "output.fields": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "name": "last_name_hebrew"
    }
  },
  
})
```

But now I need to compare the `text` values.

Comment: Can the "output.fields.name" be anything ? it sounds like it's not a constraint.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Yes it can be anything. I'm looking for those whose `name` value is `last_name_hebrew`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your first 2 condition with `$elemMatch` is correct
- add expression match, first find the matching element that having `last_name_hebrew` name from `input` using `$filter` and get first element from that filtered result using `$arrayElemAt`, same process for `output` field and then match both object using `$eq`

```
db.collection.find({
  "input.fields": { $elemMatch: { "name": "last_name_hebrew" } },
  "output.fields": { $elemMatch: { "name": "last_name_hebrew" } },
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$input.fields",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "last_name_hebrew"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$output.fields",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "last_name_hebrew"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8yHKQk3RnTZ)

---

Second option: if you want to go with more specific to match exact 2 fields `name` and `text` both just need to add `$let` operator to return fields from filter,

```
db.collection.find({
  "input.fields": { $elemMatch: { "name": "last_name_hebrew" } },
  "output.fields": { $elemMatch: { "name": "last_name_hebrew" } },
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            input: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$input.fields",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "last_name_hebrew"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: { name: "$$input.name", text: "$$input.text" }
        }
      },
      {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            output: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$output.fields",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "last_name_hebrew"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: { name: "$$output.name", text: "$$output.text" }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XZ6FwhvczUm)

---

Third option: for more specific to check both fields in loop,

- first filter the matching elements by name in input field using $filter
- pass above filter result in another filter
- filter to match name and text field in output field, if its not [] empty then return filter result
- `$ne` to check return result is not [] empty

```
db.collection.find({
  "input.fields": { $elemMatch: { "name": "last_name_hebrew" } },
  "output.fields": { $elemMatch: { "name": "last_name_hebrew" } },
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$input.fields",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.name", "last_name_hebrew"] }
            }
          },
          as: "i",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$output.fields",
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.name", "$$i.name"] },
                      { $eq: ["$$this.text", "$$i.text"] }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ReRI5df8V5M)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an aggregation pipeline to achieve this, there are several ways to do so, here is one example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$input.fields",
                as: "inputField",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$inputField.name",
                        "last_name_hebrew"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$setIsSubset": [
                        [
                          "$$inputField.text"
                        ],
                        "$output.fields.text"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6bvsIMCJaYN)
One thing to note is that with this query there are no restrictions on the `output.fields.name` (as it was not required), if you do require the names to match then you can drop the `.text` field in the `$setIsSubset` operator.

Comment: I opened your playground link and your query seems to be wrong because the input name is `last_name_hebrew` with `test1` text, but there is no any match in your `output` fields. The matching name there is `last_name_hebrew`, but the text is `test21` which is not equal to `test1`

Comment: Firstly you can just change the code there, secondly `output` and `input` are arrays, because you didn't provide extended information on how many items can be there I assumed it could be more than 1.

Comment: You are to one who answered. If your solution is wrong - you need to change it.
Did you understand that your solution is wrong?

Comment: As stated in the comments - this solution does not do the thing I asked..